# Floodlight Firewall REST API

Tags: api, rest, acl, access-control, mininet

I set up Mininet on Virtualbox and ran the following topology:

```
sudo mn --topo single,3 --mac --switch ovsk --controller=remote,ip=192.168.56.1,port=6653
```

I also ran the floodlight controller in the host machine.

When pinging all hosts under mininet they responded without problem.

```
mininet>pingall
```

The problem appears when I enable the firewall like this with the REST API:

```
curl http://192.168.56.1:8080/wm/firewall/module/enable/json
```

In this case either no respond back is received or random hosts will replay when I repeat the pingall command over and over.

And for example using the following as the only rule:

```
curl -X POST -d '{"action":"ALLOW"}' http://192.168.56.1:8080/wm/firewall/rules/json
```

what I believe should allow ping between all hosts, does not work.

I don't honestly know if I'm missing something or if this is a bug, but I couldn't find further explanation in the documentation.

For the experiment I'm using win10  and the windows firewall is all disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Firewall denies all traffic by default when enabled unless an explicit `ALLOW` rule is created.

To add an `ALLOW` rule for flows to pass through e.g switch 1 `00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01`

```
curl -X POST -d '{"switchid": "00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01"}' http://localhost:8080/wm/firewall/rules/json
```

This will allow pings between hosts directly connected to switch1 only.If you have more switches in the network, then you will have to do that for each of the switches to allow communication between hosts attached to them.

However, you can allow only specific hosts (e.g hostA(`10.0.0.3`) and hostB(`10.0.0.7`)) to communicate by explicitly specifying `ALLOW` rules from hostA to hostB and also from hostB back to hostA.

```
curl -X POST -d '{"src-ip": "10.0.0.3/32", "dst-ip": "10.0.0.7/32"}' http://localhost:8080/wm/firewall/rules/json
curl -X POST -d '{"src-ip": "10.0.0.7/32", "dst-ip": "10.0.0.3/32"}' http://localhost:8080/wm/firewall/rules/json
```

Also note: Not specifying an action implies `ALLOW` rule.
There are more you can still do,
For more see documentation: [Firewall REST API](https://floodlight.atlassian.net/wiki/display/floodlightcontroller/Firewall+REST+API)